# Vue3 Nonce / CSP

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to make a Vue3 sample spa, with csp enabled, yet all the files generated by the built break the csp rules. I see a lot of post reference to use helmet / express online, but that is all Vu2 based. Can I get some guidance on how to set a nonce on all the scripts etc, so the site can be csp enabled and safe?

Comment: Is there any luck for set nonce in vue 3 composition api?